# File not doing anything when sourced but a copy works

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file in Ubuntu that is not working for `source` and I have no idea what's happening.

```
$ cat .broken_file
export D='222'
$ cat .working_file_1
export D='88'
$ D=5
$ echo $D
5
$ source .working_file_1
$ echo $D
88
$ source .broken_file
$ ## What is happening here? It should be 222
$ echo $D
88
```

Now, both files have the same permissions:

```
$ ll .working_file_1 .broken_file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 my_user my_user
-rw-rw-r-- 1 my_user my_user
```

Moreover, if I copy the broken file, the new file just works:

```
$ cp .broken_file .broken_file_copy
$ source .broken_file_copy
$ echo $D
222
```

So it is not the contents of the file either.

I can modify my .broken_file (changing names of variables and values) and it still keeps on failing.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.16(1)-release
$ uname -srv
Linux 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 13 16:27:29 UTC 2
```

Any idea what this can be?

**Update**: `type` returns some weird information (I don't know how to interpret this):

```
$ type .broken_file
.broken_file is DIFFERENT_FOLDER/.broken_file
$ type .broken_file_copy
bash: type: .broken_file_copy: not found
```

Comment: Agreed. It may be easier to understand if you prefix cmds issued on the cmd-line with a typical prompt char (`$`), and remove the `>` chars. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter sure, changed the format

Comment: I can't replicate your problem in WSL bash. Does it help to change files perms to 755? ALSO, edit your question to show `uname -srv` and `echo $BASH_VERSION`? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter added the information

Comment: That `type` output confirms exactly what I'm saying in my answer: `.broken_file` is being resolved from the `PATH`, not from the current directory.

Comment: BTW, is `DIFFERENT_FOLDER` really a relative path? That's weird. Maybe you have a typo in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: BTW, in the general case it's more useful if you to a `type -a ....`. This shows you all occurances, in case you have in different PATH-directories files of the same name, or if you mask such a file by an alias and a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a file in your `PATH` with the same name? Info from the [Bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) on `source`:

> If *filename* does not contain a slash, the `PATH` variable is used to find *filename*, but *filename* does not need to be executable. When Bash is not in POSIX mode, it searches the current directory if *filename* is not found in `$PATH`.

Try checking with

```
type .broken_file
```

This might work instead:

```
source ./.broken_file
```

Comment: I can confirm that source ./.broken_file does work

Comment: Is there an easy way to check if there is something in the path with the same name?

Type returns very weird, I've updated the question. Does type return the resolution in the path?

Comment: `type` resolves a command name; that's exactly why I recommended it. You might be confusing it with `file`? (BTW, it also resolves other command types like aliases and functions, but you can do `type -P` if you want to avoid that. Or you could use my tool [`what`](https://github.com/wjandrea/what-bash) to get all the info, broken down.)